# Cannot clone gitlab project, Authentication failed

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I get the following error when I try and clone a project:

> Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks ls-remote https://xxx.git
>   Output: 
>   Error: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
>   remote: You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository' or 'write_repository' scope for Git over HTTP.
>   remote: You can generate one at https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens
>   fatal: Authentication failed for 'xxx.git/'

I have generated a .pub using `ssh-keygen -t xxx -C "xxx"`

How can I clone the repo in `sourcetree`?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61589547/12116796

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, every project in gitlab will have two types of cloning urls. One is http and another is ssh.

Now that you have setup the ssh key, you should be able to clone it using ssh url.

Not sure how you did setup your ssh key. but you can find some instructions in below link.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/