# Gitlab clone project: authentication failed

Tags: gitlab

I tried to simply clone a Gitlab project jusing both HTTPS and SSH and they both don't work and print back an atuhentication failed message.

When trying with https address:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/project.aa/project.git

Cloning into 'frontend'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/project.aa/project.git'
```

And with my SSH key that's the message I get:

```
Cloning into 'frontend'...
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What can I do?

Comment: You've tried `git clone git://gitlab.com/project.aa/project.git` ?

Comment: the command with `git://` freezes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try log-out and login with the same credentials that you're trying to use for cloning the repository. If the problem persists: In Windows, Search for `Credential Manager`. In that choose `Windows manager`. Select your Gitlab credentials and modify it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had to modify the credentials

Comment: I have the same problem but I am at Linux Ubuntu how can I resolve?